# Make Firefox go to first result when query typed in address bar?

Tags: firefox, search-engines, address-bar, google-search

I have just installed Firefox 17 on Windows 7.

When I search by writing a word in the address bar and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> I am not being redirected to the first result automatically.

How can I make Firefox go to the first result (of the Google search) automatically?

Comment: By the way: All google searches I did for this found how to disable such a thing, not enable it

Comment: If you found out how to disable it, can't you just reverse the process to turn it on?

Comment: @martineau - disabling it is done by deleting something on the about:config settings, it didn't say what was written there in the first place

Comment: Well, tell us what the setting name is and maybe someone who still has it can tell you what it should be. You can also often search for the settings name + "FireFox" and find information about it's value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is make the address bar search engine use the "I'm Feeling Lucky" Google Search instead of a normal Google Search.

> ### **"I'm Feeling Lucky" Google Search**
>
> When a user types in a search and clicks on the button **the user will
>   be taken directly to the first search result, bypassing the search
>   engine results page**. The thought is that if a user is "feeling lucky",
>   the search engine will return the perfect match the first time without
>   having to page through the search results

To search using the "I'm Feeling Lucky" Google Search by default when typing a query in the address bar:

1. Go to the `about:config` page in Firefox.
2. Locate the preference `keyword.URL`.
3. Right click the preference `keyword.URL`, click "Modify", and enter the following URL:

   ```
   http://www.google.com/search?btnI=I%27m+Feeling+Lucky&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=
   ```

Any search query will be added after the `q=`, therefore searching through "I'm Feeling Lucky" instead of through a regular Google Search.